# Delphi 10.4 - How to modify the parameters of an element of a StyleBook at runtime?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In **Delphi 10.4**, I would like to modify the color of one element (**backgroundstyle**) in a **StyleBook** at run time
I tried

`StyleBook1.Styles.StyleData['backgroundstyle.Fill.Color'] := TalphaColors.Blue;`

and/or

`StyleBook1.StyleContainer['backgroundstyle.Fill.Color'] := TalphaColors.Blue;`

but I have the following error messages 'undclared identifier'...

Does someone have an idea ?
Thank's a lot
[image]

Comment: Create and change the StyleName property instead to change it in the StyleBook

Comment: I tried ( backgroundstyle is the StyleName )

 ```StyleBook1.Styles.StyleData['backgroundstyle.Fill.Color'] := TalphaColors.Blue;```


but I have the following error messages 'undclared identifier'...

Comment: Read my comment below, create a backgroundstyle and a backgroundstyleblue that you set to your object/form

Comment: Thank's for your answer and your time
I know that I can "manually" create different backgroundstyle and set it to my object
But what I wanted to do is to change the color of one style by code and not manually...so for example I could ask the user to select a color and after to apply this color on some elements of my StyleBook. 
But it seam that it is not possible ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing an s in StyleBook1.Styles.StylesData